# Receiving a stack overflow exception when I run my code, multiple recursion calls.

Tags: c#, exception, recursion

I believe these specific lines of code is the cause of the error.

Are there any work around for this? z holds the value of a static int variable for objects of type grid. For this code, there is a grid of a random size. At the beginning of the code, a single grid point "walks" to two other grid points, and then each of those grid points "walks" to two more grid points and so on.

The recursion is suppose to stop when there has been 3000 walks. The number of walks gets updated every single time a grid point is "walked" too. So the number of walks is a static variable of the coordinate class which is the type of object that composes each grid point.

A coordinate is nothing more than and x and y component. "int a" and "int b" are parameters that accept the "x" and "y" grid components respectively in the Recurs method. The x and y components are assigned randomly in the recursiveWalk method.

```
//Walks
    public void Recurs(int a, int b)
    {
        grid[a, b].updateAccessed();
        grid[a, b].setWalkCount();
        int z = grid[a, b].getWalkCount();
        if (z == 3000)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int one = rand.Next(20);
            int two = rand.Next(20);
            //int three = rand.Next(20);
            int four = rand.Next(25);
            int five = rand.Next(25);
            //int six = rand.Next(25);
            Recurs(one, four);
            Recurs(two, five);
            //Recurs(three, six);
        }
    }

    //Walks to any grid point recursively
    public void RecursiveWalk()
    {
        int x = rand.Next(20);
        int y = rand.Next(25);
        Recurs(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: You are recursing until you hit a grid location that has been walked on 3000 times? Yeah, I can see that overflowing the stack.. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: There's not really any point using recursion here. You might as well just use a loop. You're just picking random locations until you get one with a "walk count" of 3000 (presumably, one that you've randomly hit 3000 times)

Comment: I edited the question to clarify my intentions. I'm not sure how to achieve my goal without using recursion, it seems to be the cleanest approach. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I still don't really understand, I think. I've added an answer with some iterative code that, as far as I can tell, does pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling Recurs twice in each recursion? Can you change your condition?

```
//Walks
public void Recurs(int a, int b)
{
    grid[a, b].updateAccessed();
    grid[a, b].setWalkCount();
    int z = grid[a, b].getWalkCount();

    //i assume in 1 of your recursion, 
    //the count was set to 3001 and it continues

    if (z >= 3000)   //<-- >= instead of =
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int one = rand.Next(20);
        int two = rand.Next(20);
        //int three = rand.Next(20);
        int four = rand.Next(25);
        int five = rand.Next(25);
        //int six = rand.Next(25);
        Recurs(one, four);
        Recurs(two, five);
        //Recurs(three, six);
    }
}

//Walks to any grid point recursively
public void RecursiveWalk()
{
    int x = rand.Next(20);
    int y = rand.Next(25);
    Recurs(x, y);
}
```

Comment: I changed my condition like you said and I did not get the exception. Is there any way to ensure it stops when z == 3000, instead of >= 3000? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: to do that, you can either loop it 3000 times like what @Blorgbeard suggested for simplicity, or you need a singleton int z that locks and unlocks during updates

Comment: i correct myself, is setWalkCount(), some method that increments your counter? If so, why don't you return a boolean when it hits a specified limit during your grid object construction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to use recursion for this at all. Can you simply use a loop, like this?

```
public void IterativeWalk() 
{
    for (int z=0; z<3000; z++) 
    {
        int x = rand.Next(20);
        int y = rand.Next(25);
        grid[x, y].updateAccessed();
        grid[x, y].setWalkCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason why I don't use an iterative walk is because each grid point randomly walks to 3 other grid points, instead of 1 which is what your IterativeWalk() method achieves.

Comment: I don't understand why that matters.. When you say "walk", do you mean anything more complicated than picking a random grid position? And why do you say "each grid point walks"? It doesn't seem to be the point that does the walking, if you see what I mean. You're not picking a random neighbour, you're just picking a totally random position - so the current grid position has no effect on the next chosen position. It looks like you are just picking 3000 random grid positions, which is what my code does in a simpler way.

Comment: Perhaps this will clarify. First you start off with a single random grid position, that first position randomly selects 3 other grid positions, and then each of those 3 grid position randomly selects another 3 grid locations and so on. This is supposed to continue until a total of 3,000 grid positions have been visited. Does that make it clearer? In your code, each of the grid positions that are selected does not branch off to 3 other grid locations. I hope this clarifies anything you don't understand about my problem.

Comment: Ok, but that sounds like implementation details. I don't see the practical difference: the end result is still just 3000 random positions, whichever way you get there. Unless there is something happening that I don't see in the code.. When you say "that first position randomly selects 3 other grid positions", what do you mean? In what way does the *grid position* do any selecting?

Comment: My apologies, the grid position doesn't select anything, its the Recur() method that does the selection. I don't see how I can implement what I am trying to do through iteration instead of recursion.

Comment: Well, I guess you have it sorted out now anyway.. But I still don't see how the iterative method above doesn't do what you want. If you replaced your method with mine, would you be able to tell the difference just by looking at the output of your program, rather than the code?

Comment: You're right that the output would be the same. However, the implementation is the important part, your iterative method does not contain 3 random grid point selections per random grid point selection. I appreciate your feedback and help!

Comment: I see.. Well, it sounds like your requirement boils down to "I want to use recursion", so I guess iteration will not work for you :P

Comment: Haha, again i appreciate the feedback.